# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE Exception While Running Appium Android Test

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I'm working with an Appium Android Test. I didn't have any problems with my test and it was working well. After few weeks, I tried to run it again (without any changes) and now I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:71)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:57)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:60)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.getDefaultHttpClientFactory(ApacheHttpClient.java:251)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.<init>(ApacheHttpClient.java:228)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.getDefaultClientFactory(HttpCommandExecutor.java:96)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:70)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.<init>(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:36)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:167)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:69)
at QA.Test.setUp(Test.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.<init>(AbstractVerifier.java:5)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier.<init>(AllowAllHostnameVerifier.java:5)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:124)
... 39 more
```

Current POM.xml file dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.48.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>nu.pattern</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.9-7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also here's setUp:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.4.13");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.3");
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "<app_package>");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "<app_activity>");
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

> **(I get the error in the last line while debugging)**

**Once again:** I didn't have this error and I didn't change anything.

**Edit:** I've upgraded 'java-client' and then I got the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
```

And then I've added hamcrest-core jar file to my project. Now I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:71)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:57)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:60)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.getDefaultHttpClientFactory(ApacheHttpClient.java:251)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.<init>(ApacheHttpClient.java:228)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.<init>(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:50)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:77)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:67)
at QA.Test.setUp(Test.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

java.lang.NullPointerException
at QA.Test.tearDown(Test.java:200)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: The exception used as the message title and the exception in the message body are totally different???

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry, I've pasted another error by mistake. Thank you for warning.

Comment: might be appium has been upgraded, try removing appium version capabiltiy and run

Comment: Nothing changes. @karthick23

Comment: upgrade ur java-client, seems to be too old

Comment: Can you recheck might be java updated

Comment: Now I have "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing" exception @karthick23

Comment: And I added "hamcrest-core" jar. And now I get following exception:

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Comment: Java is up to date @SadikAli

Comment: good we have solved that error, make sure ur pom points to updated jar and update the question with ur code to check where is the keyword INSTANCE

Answer (score 2):

This is a dependency issue caused by http request,

Two reasons, may be ur referring **more than one** **http-jar** in ur class path -remove and keep only one

or there is no http jar to perform http req- add http core jar something like,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works now. But it's slower now, I guess, I'll check its details. Thanks again!

Comment: feel free to upvote the question if it helped u. Thanks

Comment: I've already upvoted.  It just can't seem public because of that my reputation is not enough yet. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I've upgraded java-client and then updated POM.xml
I had still same issue but I added http-client and http-core to jar library. And it works now. Thank you @karthick23